# How do you create dynamic local store based on record property

Tags: extjs, store

I have an integer field on backend. This field is an offset (CPI Index delay) that could takes values from 0 -> N. On frontend I want to display a combo box with this value / label:

```
{key: 0, label: "0 - 21/06/2020"}
{key: 1, label: "1 - 21/06/2021"}
{key: 2, label: "2 - 21/06/2022"}
{key: 3, label: "3 - ...       "}
```

The number of option is calculated this way: `rent_end_date.year` - `first_due_date.year`. Each time the `first_due_date` change, the options of the combo box must be calculated again.

To achieve this I've initialed a variabile `indexOffsetChoices` with relative formula to calculate choices each time a `first_due_date` changes:

```
viewModel: {
    type: 'rentsdetailformmodel',
    data: {
        hideRentsDetailGrids: false,
        indexOffsetChoices: []
    },
    formulas: {
        calculateIndexOffsetChoices: {
            bind: '{detailRecord.first_due_date}',
            get: function (firstDueDate) {
                var detailRecord = this.get('detailRecord'),
                    indexOffset = detailRecord.get('index_offset'),
                    rentEndDate = detailRecord.get('end_date');
                if (indexOffset !== undefined && rentEndDate !== undefined) {
                    var choices = [];
                    for (i = 0; i < (rentEndDate.getFullYear() - firstDueDate.getFullYear()); i++) {
                        var RawCPIDate = new Date(firstDueDate.setFullYear(firstDueDate.getFullYear() + i)),
                            CPIDateFmt = Ext.Date.format(new Date(RawCPIDate), 'd/m/Y'),
                            label = i + ' - ' + CPIDateFmt;
                        choices.push({"key": i, "label": label});
                    }
                    this.indexOffsetChoices = choices;
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Then I added my combo box with an inline local store that point to the viewModel variable `indexOffsetChoices`:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    name: 'index_offset',
    reference: 'index_offset',
    fieldLabel: 'CPI Application Delay',
    valueField: 'key',
    displayField: 'label',
    queryMode: 'local',
    bind: '{detailRecord.index_offset}',
    store: {
        type: 'store',
        storeId: 'rent__index_offset',
        idProperty: 'key',
        fields: ['key', 'label'],
        data: this.indexOffsetChoices
    }
}]
```

But the data are not loaded. This is the right approach? How do you create local store based on records / dynamic data? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You did the hardest way sir! The `'data'` property in viewModel is actually not used to store large of array data except you will work hard to modify them.

Setting dynamic options in combobox can be achieved by updating (or re-setting) it's options (using `yourcombofield.setOptions([/*new array data*/])` like [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/modern/Ext.field.ComboBox.html#method-setOptions) ) or it's data store (using `yourcombofield.getStore().setData([/* new array data*/])` like [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#method-setData)) or if you declare your store in viewModel `'stores'` property like [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#cfg-stores) and have linked to your combobox's `store` property, you don't need to access combobox again, just modify the array data of the store and your combobox's options which has been linked to the store will be updated automatically. The important thing, try to give the easiest way to modify you array data inside the store.

Now, let's talk about when and where will you place your code to update this combobox's data? This is about the event's owner which you want to listen (and also affects your case). You said "Each time the `first_due_date` change". If `first_due_date` is affected by another field, just put your code inside it's `change/keyup/keydown` listeners and then re-treat you data by filtering,removing,adding, etc and the last, update the old data with the new data where ever the data has been stored before.